# Is there any way to add all the dependencies(minimum) to a react app?

Tags: reactjs

When we are creating a React app we are installing individual dependencies. Is there any way to add all the dependencies say minimal in a React app(Like we do in pom.xml). Some dependencies I mentioned here which I install one by one.

```
npm install -S yup
npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap@4.6.0
npm install axios
npm add formik
npm install react-icons --save
npm install --save react-toastify
npm install --save react-modal
npm install react-tooltip
npm add react-countup
npm install react-player
npm i react-charts --save
npm install react-router-dom
npm install react-table --save
npm add date-fns
```

Comment: You could create a base `package.json` file for your projects that has all the minimum requirements, then just copy and paste it around wherever you need it.

Comment: Or use a script, or create your own app template, or create a package used only for its dependencies (this can get a little sketchy, though, since they're non-explicit dependencies, which can be confusing), or...